# Create table and sort data from lists in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that includes lists

```
    students = {
1:["name1", 20, 100],
2:["name2", 20, 100],
3:["name3", 20, 95],
4:["name4", 21, 65],
5:["name5", 22, 85]
}
```

I want to create table and sort the data by names. like this

```
Name        Age       Score
name1       20        100
name2       20        100
name3       20        95
name4       21        65
name5       22        85
```

How can I do this?
I wrote like this:

```
students = {
1:["Rauf", 20, 100],
2:["Shafag", 20, 100],
3:["Ali", 20, 95],
4:["Camal", 21, 65],
5:["Arzu", 22, 85]

}
print(" ")
print("{:>12} {:>12} {:>12}".format('Name','Age','Score'))
print(" ")
for v in students.values():
    name, age, score = v
    print(sorted(("{:>12} {:>12} {:>12}".format(name, age, score)), key= lambda v: v[2]))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any attempt might do.

Comment: StackOverflow is not supposed to do your homework. Show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @TEHEMPRAH I edited. It is not my homework. I just can't sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using f-strings (Python 3.6+) and `map`, you can simply syntax and make your code more efficient. You need `sorted` to sort by name.

```
import operator
students = {1:["Rauf", 20, 100],
            2:["Shafag", 20, 100],
            3:["Ali", 20, 95],
            4:["Camal", 21, 65],
            5:["Arzu", 22, 85]}

print(" ")
print(f"{'Name':>12} {'Age':>12} {'Score':>12}")
sorted_students = sorted(students.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(" ")
for name, age, score in map(itemgetter(1), sorted_students):
    print(f"{name:>12} {age:>12} {score:>12}")
```

Result:

```
    Name          Age        Score

     Ali           20           95
    Arzu           22           85
   Camal           21           65
    Rauf           20          100
  Shafag           20          100
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help

```
import operator
students = {
1:["Rauf", 20, 100],
2:["Shafag", 20, 100],
3:["Ali", 20, 95],
4:["Camal", 21, 65],
5:["Arzu", 22, 85]

}
print(" ")
print("{:>12} {:>12} {:>12}".format('Name','Age','Score'))
sorted_students = sorted(students.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(" ")
for v in sorted_students:
    name, age, score = v[1]
    print("{:>12} {:>12} {:>12}".format(name, age, score))
```

Comment: yes first I wrote like this. but as I said I wnat to sort the data by name. I can't find the correct way